# How to update constraints after dynamic type's UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios, autolayout, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

The view uses Readable Content Guides to layout the subviews but the constraints doesn't update when the user changes the text size in the Accessibility settings. I implemented the  `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` and tried `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` and `layoutIfNeeded` to see if the layout changes but that doesn't work. The `UITableView` does that automatically but other `UIViews` don't.

(Screenshots doesn't change the text size because I'm still implementing Dynamic Font sizes but the table header and cells are using the `readableLayoutGuide`.)

**First run:**

[image: Screen on first run]

**After changing the text size in settings:**

[image: Screen after changing the text size]

Any way to force that update so the UI can be responsive to text size changes while it's running, without restarting the app (when I restart, it applies the new size successfully).

Comment: Automatic response to dynamic type depends on you using one of the Text Styles e.g Body, Callout, Caption 1 etc . If you are using your own sizes and styles you'd need all the associated `UIFontMetrics` mech to get responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

The text styles **and** the `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`property are **mandatory** to use the `Dynamic Type` as you wish *(I hope you did it first)*.

When handling the font size change event, you must **redisplay the affected elements** as the code snippet explains in [this site](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#text-size) if you're programming an application in iOS10 at least.

About the standard table view cells content, it is automatically adjusted thanks to the cell-sizing feature.

Everything is well explained in the `Building Apps with Dynamic Type` WWDC [video detailed summary](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) where all the contents and their video timelapse are indicated to reach rapidly the information.

I suggest you take a look at the example section where solutions are provided for basic `Dynamic Type` pitfalls.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it has valuable information but it didn't solved my issue. I guess my issue is a bug in the `UIKit` because the `readableLayoutGuide` should update the layout automatically when the content size changes and it doesn't.

Comment: @ricardopereira: if you think that's a bug, don't hesitate to write an accepted answer to let people know that's the solution so as they don't waste time searching for nothing, please. ;o)